# ICS from XP (Wireless & LAN) to Vista (LAN)

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, networking, ics

I'm trying to get my new Vista Ultimate computer to share the wireless connection my XP Pro computer has via a LAN using an old Linksys router I have.  After 2 days I finally got my XP computer to be able to access the internet and share files via the LAN, and the Vista computer can share files but cannot access the internet using the XP's wireless connection.

XP Computer:
 - Has wireless USB connection.  Wired to router.
 - Can access both internet and share files on LAN
 - Internet connection sharing (ICS) is setup for the wireless connection.
 - Wireless Info:  IP - 192.168.1.81, Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0, Gateway: 192.168.1.254
 - Wired LAN Info: IP - 192.168.110.3, Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0, Gateway: (blank)

Vista Computer:
 - Has LAN (connected to router) and can share files
 - No Internet Access
 - Wired LAN Info: IP - 192.168.110.2, Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0, Gateway: (blank)
 - IPv6 Disabled
 - I see "Residential Gateway Device" in my network, in properties it says "Model: Internet Connection Sharing" but I can't do anything with it

Linksys Router:
 - IP Address set to 192.168.110.1
 - DHCP Disabled

How can I get my Vista computer to have internet access too?  (I don't have wireless for it to connect to the wireless network directly, nor can I access that router directly).  I feel I am so close after messing with it for 2 days...  any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

you're connecting to the internet via the wireless USB connection on the XP computer and this connection is shared?

manually configure the LAN connection TCP/IP settings on the XP computer:

IP 192.168.0.1
subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
no gateway, no DNS

now configure your router (use the Vista computer, the XP machine cannot connect to the router now) for static WAN

IP 192.168.0.2
Gateway: 192.168.0.1

the trick is: not the Vista computer, the router has to get the internet connection from the XP computer, then you can access the internet through the router from the Vista computer. thus you have to make sure that your XP computer is connected to the WAN port of your router.

however, if you want to share files between the 2 computers, you'll need a second NIC for the XP computer to connect to a LAN port in the router.

alternatively, do away with the router and get a [crossover network cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) (Vista computer either to automatic IP or 192.168.0.2, subnet 255.255.255.0, gateway and DNS 192.168.0.1). now can have both, internet connection AND file/printer sharing.